# htaccess forward but does not uses parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a quite simple rewrite rule, it works meaning the rewrite works but the parameter does not reach the destination page.

Each page has a section, title and a id.

The url has dashes in the name and I use a underscore separator to separate the id.

- The section name is hypnose
- The title is Hoe-werkt-hypnose
- The id is 4

**The rewrite rule:**

`RewriteRule ^hypnose/([^/.]+)_([^/.]+).php$  hypnose.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L]`

**The url that i'm using**

`hypnose/Hoe-werkt-hypnose_4.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn `MultiViews` option off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^hypnose/([^/_]+)_([^/.]+)\.php$ hypnose.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.